# Views Aggregator Plus enumeration, How can I access resulting data to create link to google maps

Tags: views

I have geolatlon field for 10 locations.  The view enumerates the geolatlon lat/long and shows it correctly in the footer.(10 lat/long pairs separated by / )  Trying to now access the data as a string to add/create a link.
When I manually copy the enumerated geolatlon data from the footer and paste into maps.google.com, it works great.  I need to make a link for users.(ie: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/ +the enumerated geolatlon data pairs)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Changed the question. Hopefully more clear now.